# Responsive List django. Broken alignment on phone device

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I'm building a "Family Tree" website using django but I have a problem.

This is my list when i use computer
[image: computer list]
if I use my mobile phone i have this
[image: mobile list]

I use library django-mptt to build this list:

```
<ul class="root">
{% recursetree GT %}
    <br><li>
        <details open class="detail"> 
        <summary><a href="{% url 'person-detail' node.id %}?id={{node.id}}">{{ node.name }} </a><span><sup>{% if node.date_birthday|date:'d.m' == '01.01' %} ({{node.date_birthday|date:'Y'}} - {{node.date_death|date:'Y'}} г.г) {% else %}({{node.date_birthday|date:'d.m.Y'}} - {{node.date_death|date:'d.m.Y'}} г.г){% endif %}</sup></span></summary>
        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
            <ul class="children">
                <a href="#">{{ children }}</a
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </details>
    </li>
{% endrecursetree %}
```

my css look like:

```
.root li a{
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
color: #524f4e;
} 
.root li a::before{
content: '';
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 0%;
height: 2px;
background-color: #2D764A;
transition: 0.3s;
}
.root li a:hover:before {
width: 100%;
left: 0;
}
.root li{
list-style-type:none;
color:  green;
}

.root li span{
color: black;
}
.Maingenwrite{
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}




.detail summary{
position: absolute;

}
```

How can I make a responsive list using CSS or JS so that it displays correctly on the phone ?

Comment: What does your CSS code look like for now?

Comment: It's still difficult to tell... Could you try removing `.detail summary {position: absolute;}`?